# Same configuration of all Label Widgets in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to use same configuration in the labels I want. For example, we put configuration in a variable and use as required:

```
from tkinter import *
mainWindow = Tk()

mainFrame = Frame(mainWindow,bg="Red")
mainFrame.pack(fill="both",expand=True)

# Create a variable that contains the configuration for Label
LabelSettings = '''font=("Arial", 18),bg="Black",  fg="white", padx=5, pady=5'''

label = Label(mainFrame,text="Vertical Frame Example")
label.config(LabelSettings)
label.pack(fill="x")

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you make `LabelSettings` a dictionary, you can put `**LabelSettings` in either the initial creation of the Label, or in a `.config()` call, to insert all of the dict's items as if they were keyword arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could be also doing is making the options in a dictionary and then passing it on to the `config()` method, like:

```
LabelSettings = {'font':("Arial", 18),'bg':"Black",'fg':"white",'padx':5, 'pady':5}
....
label.config(LabelSettings)
```

And, if you want to pass it onto the initial creation of the widget, then you will need to specify it as keyword argument(**) in your example, like:

```
label = Label(mainFrame,text="Vertical Frame Example",**LabelSettings)
```

As said by jasonharper.

Or you could also replace your `label.config(LabelSettings)` with:

```
exec(f'label.config({LabelSettings})') #might not be recommended
```

Answer (score 3):

Tkinter maintains an internal database of default option values (called the *options database*). If you want to change the default for all widgets, you can just change the database value and all widgets will pick up the changes unless overridden by a specific widget.

For example, you could add the following to your code to achieve what you want:

```
mainWindow.option_add("*Label*Font", ("Helvetica", 32))
mainWindow.option_add("*Label*Foreground", "white")
mainWindow.option_add("*Label*Background", "red")
mainWindow.option_add("*Label*padX", 5)
mainWindow.option_add("*Label*padY", 5)
```

Comment: mainWindow.option_add worked for Label and Entry. However it did not work in case of Grid. How to set defaults for Grid for sticky="nsew" or padx=10

Comment: @sambajaj: you can't. The option database is for widget options.

Comment: Hmm. I am now putting common GRID settings inside a variable. Example: `GridSetting = {'sticky':"NSEW", 'pady':3, 'ipady':5}` and using it like this: `SomeWidget.grid(row = 0, column = 5,  **GridSetting)` ...as suggested by jasonharper & Cool Cloud. Its working.

Comment: @sambajaj: yes, of course that works. That's not using the option database. The option database is for widget options, not options for just any function or object.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
mainWindow = Tk()

mainFrame = Frame(mainWindow,bg="Red")
mainFrame.pack(fill="both",expand=True)
```

Store everything in a separate variable, so it's easier to change.

```
# Create a variable that contains the 
configuration for Label
labelFont = ('Arial',18)
labelBG = 'Black'
labelFG = 'white'
labelPadx = 5
labelPady = 5

label = Label(mainFrame,text="Vertical Frame 
Example")
label.config(font = labelFont, bg = labelBG, fg = 
labelFG, padx = labelPadx, pady = labelPady)
label.pack(fill="x")

mainWindow.mainloop()
```